# jQuery integer array usually sets as null in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I am encountering an error while sending an integer array to a method. I am passing data as shown below. I also tried to send an integer array parameter in various format, for example using JSON.stringfy, but this parameter is usually null.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".findItem", function () {

    var items = "[" + $("#hdnItem").val() + "]";

    var itemData = {
        ids: items,
        year: $(".year").val()
    };

    alert(items); //[n1, n2, n3, ..]

    $.post("@Url.Action("GetItem", "Home")", $.param(itemData, true), function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
            console.log(v);
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetItem(int[] ids, short year)
{
    //some code
    return Json(item, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: You are using `[HttpGet]` attribute and using `$.post()` method

Comment: To generate your array use `var items = []; items.push($("#hdnItem").val());`

Comment: Thanks for your aid, i solved this issue as you specified.

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery**

```
$(document).on("click", ".findItem", function () {

    var items = []; 
    items.push($("#hdnItem").val());

    var itemData = {
        ids: items,
        year: $(".year").val()
    };

    alert(items); //[n1, n2, n3,..]

    $.post("@Url.Action("GetItem", "Home")", $.param(itemData, true), function (data) {

        console.log(data.lenght);

        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
            console.log(v);
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost] //Must be POST
public JsonResult GetItem(int[] ids, short year)
{
    //some code
    return Json(item, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```